# Why does $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty }\arctan\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)dx$ have a real value when the indefinite integral uses $i$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral(%20(%20arctan%20(1%2F(x%C2%B2%2B1))),%20x%3D-infty%20to%20infty) gives a *real* closed form for this definite integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty } \arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\right)dx = \sqrt{2\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)}\;\pi$$

Yet, the formula it gives for the *indefinite* integral uses $i$.

$$\int \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x^2 + 1}\right) dx = x \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x^2 + 1}\right) 
+ 2 \left(
\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - i}}\right)}{(1 - i)^{3/2}} 
+ 
\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + i}}\right)}{(1 + i)^{3/2}}
\right) + C$$

> Why isn't the definite integral non-real?

Comment: How is $$\sqrt{2 (\sqrt{2}-1)} π$$ a complex number?

Comment: @PeterForeman , I meant why the result dosn't includes the complex number x+iy with non null imaginary part

Comment: But the above result is clearly a real number. I don't understand your confusion

Comment: Just because an expression has $i$ in it doesn't mean it lies outside $\mathbb{R}$. E.g., $i^2$.

Comment: Note that replacing $i$ with $-i$ in $(1+i)^{-3/2}\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+i}}$ replaces the original complex number with its complex conjugate. The result is real viz. $z+z^\ast\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: @J.G. The good thinh here is the integral representation to pi with nice closed form

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: I edited your question to make it more self-contained and to make your point of confusion more clear. Please double-check that I didn't change your intent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, it is real because it converges and because $\arctan\left(\frac1{1+x^2}\right)$ is a real number for every $x\in \mathbb R$.

On the other hand, that some number can be represented with an expression involving $i$ doesn't mean it is not a real number. For instance,
$$\frac1i+i=0\in \mathbb R.$$

Answer (score 4):

WolframAlpha, though handy, is not yet advanced to perform certain integrals satisfactorily. For less familiar integrands, it tends to fall back to complex variables, leading often to uninteresting, perhaps only symbolically useful, results.

The integral in question can be integrated in real variables explicitly

\begin{align}
\int \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\ dx &
= x\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\\
&\>\>\>+\sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}-1)}\tan^{-1}\frac{x^2-\sqrt{2}}{x\sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}+1)}} \\
& \>\>\>- \sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}+1)}\tanh^{-1}\frac{x^2+\sqrt{2}}{x\sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}-1)}}+C
\end{align}

which eludes WA due to limitations in its current algorithm.

Comment: How did you figure out $I_1$ and $I_2$ explicitly?

Comment: Though I agree with your point. Mathematica can't deal with my last rational integral at all, it gives a general answer in terms of polynomial roots

Comment: Wait how did you find this antiderivative? I tried for a while but I couldn’t get to your result :(

Comment: @CaptainChicky - integrate by parts to turn the integrand to a rational fractional form

Answer (score 1):

A pretty integral, and I'm not sure I would be able to guess the primitive right away.

Still, substitution is always a good way to simplify things:

$$I=\int_a^b \arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\right)dx, \\ 0 \leq a<b$$

---

$$x= \tan t$$

$$I=\int_{\arctan a}^{\arctan b} \arctan\left(\cos^2 t\right)\frac{dt}{\cos^2 t}$$

$$u = \cos t$$

$$I=\int_{\cos \arctan b}^{\cos \arctan a} \arctan\left(u^2 \right)\frac{du}{u^2 \sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

$$I=\int_{1/\sqrt{1+b^2}}^{1/\sqrt{1+a^2}} \arctan\left(u^2 \right)\frac{du}{u^2 \sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

$$v=u^2$$

$$I=\frac{1}{2} \int_{1/(1+b^2)}^{1/(1+a^2)} \arctan v \frac{dv}{v^{3/2} \sqrt{1-v}}$$

Now we can use integration by parts:

$$\int \frac{1}{2} \frac{dv}{v^{3/2} \sqrt{1-v}}=-\frac{\sqrt{1-v}}{\sqrt{v}}$$

$$(\arctan v)'= \frac{1}{1+v^2}$$

$$I=-\sqrt{\frac{1}{v}-1} \arctan v \bigg|_{1/(1+b^2)}^{1/(1+a^2)}+ \int_{1/(1+b^2)}^{1/(1+a^2)} \frac{\sqrt{1-v} ~dv}{\sqrt{v} (1+v^2)}$$

> $$I=b \arctan \frac{1}{1+b^2}-a \arctan \frac{1}{1+a^2} + 2 \int_{1/\sqrt{1+b^2}}^{1/\sqrt{1+a^2}} \frac{\sqrt{1-u^2} ~du}{1+u^4}$$

For the second part we get back to trigonometric functions again:

$$\int_{1/\sqrt{1+b^2}}^{1/\sqrt{1+a^2}} \frac{\sqrt{1-u^2} ~du}{1+u^4}=\int_{\arcsin(1/\sqrt{1+b^2})}^{\arcsin(1/\sqrt{1+a^2})} \frac{\cos^2 w}{1+\sin^4 w} dw$$

Now we use the tangent half angle substitution:

$$p = \tan \frac{w}{2} \\ \cos w= \frac{1-p^2}{1+p^2} \\ \sin w= \frac{2p}{1+p^2} \\ dw = \frac{2dp}{1+p^2}$$

Denoting:

$$\alpha= \tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \arcsin \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2}} \right) \\ \beta =  \tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \arcsin \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+b^2}} \right)$$

> $$\int_{1/\sqrt{1+b^2}}^{1/\sqrt{1+a^2}} \frac{\sqrt{1-u^2} ~du}{1+u^4}=\int_{\beta}^{\alpha} \frac{2 (1-p^2)^2 (1+p^2) }{(1+p^2)^4+16 p^4} dp$$

Now we have a rational function under the integral, which can be integrated using partial fractions.

I will stop here, because the point was, we don't really need CAS to integrate this, and no complex numbers were harmed in the process.

Well, it might be much easier to do the partial fractions in the last integral using complex numbers. But I'm sure we can avoid them.

Note that for the case in the OP, we have:

$$a=0, b=\infty$$

Which means we need to find:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{ (1-p^2)^2 (1+p^2) }{(1+p^2)^4+16 p^4} dp= \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}} ~ \pi$$

I confirmed this value numerically, but Mathematica can't find it from the integral.

Though it does find:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{ (1-p^2)^2 (1+p^2) }{(1+p^2)^4+16 p^4} dp= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}} ~ \pi$$

To be honest, complex residues seems like the best method in this case to me.